# Can we prove $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1$ using just their series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, proof-explanation

In particular I mean:

$$\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2$$

$$=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^2$$

However I am not sure how you're supposed to correctly expand and recombine terms when dealing with the sum of two squared series, especially when there are factorials involved.

Edit: To be clear, I am asking about manipulating the series I have just stated in order to show that they sum to $1$.

Comment: Hint: differentiate $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2$.

Comment: @Wojowu that's not what the question is asking; OP is asking if we can prove it directly from the series.

Comment: @OP you can use the Cauchy product of two series to expand the squared sums. Terms should cancel out nicely

Comment: @user369210: It is a valid answer to the OPs question. The Taylor series can be differentiated to get the desired answer.

Comment: The answer to this is "yes" - all the operations turn out to be well defined expanding, recombining, squaring and adding factorials - cancellations work as required. Limits are not a problem.

Comment: @copper.hat its not worth arguing about this, but Wojowu's comment implied that OP should compute $2 \sin x \cos x - 2 \cos x \sin x = 0$

Comment: Look up multiplication of power series

Comment: @user369210 Ah, I see now OP wants to do this by expanding and manipulating the two series; I agree differentiating doesn't accomplish this.

Comment: Just treat the series like a "long polynomial" when you square it.  For example, the coefficient of $x^6$ the series for $\sin^2x$ is $$\frac{2}{1!5!}+\frac{1}{3!3!}$$

Comment: I am specifically asking about manipulating the series as stated in the main post to show that their sum is 1. I'm aware of the other tricks (Pythagorean theorem, Euler's formula, etc).

Comment: @user539262 now it is clear but as the OP was formulated it wasn't clear, anyway since Euler formula is obtained by series it is not to br considered a trick in my opinion but how the best way to apply series, if you are looking for a more complicated wat it's ok but you need to declare it as you have made now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. Power series actually multiply just like polynomials do: $$(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\ldots)(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\ldots)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{c=0}^na_cb_{n-c}\right)x^n.$$

Let $$\alpha(x)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2$$
$$\beta(x)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^2.$$
First, it is clear that the constant term of $\alpha(x)+\beta(x)$ is indeed $1$, as we can check directly. Thus, we merely need to check that every other coefficient vanishes.

Note that, either from the formula for products or by noting that both are even functions, all the coefficients of odd powers of $x$ in both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and thus $\alpha+\beta$ vanish. Now, consider the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in either. In $\beta$, the formula gives the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ as, where we use the variable $k$ to count only the even (non-zero) coefficients of $\cos(x)$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^c\cdot (-1)^{n-k}\cdot \frac{1}{(2n-2k)!}\cdot \frac{1}{(2k)!}=(-1)^n\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}.$$
The same can be done to find the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in $\alpha$, using $k$ to enumerate odd coefficients of $\sin(x)$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\cdot (-1)^{n-k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{(2n-2k-1)!}\cdot \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2n-2k-1)!}.$$
We are trying to show that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\alpha+\beta$ is zero for $n>0$. This amounts to showing the following equality for all $n>0$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!(2n-2k-1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}.$$
Multiplying through by $(2n)!$ on both sides reduces this to a combinatorial equality:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{2n\choose 2k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n{2n\choose 2k}.$$
This just says that the number of subsets of $2n$ with an odd number of elements equals the number of subsets of $2n$ with an even number of elements - but this is easy to show: We can define a bijection $\pi$ which takes a set $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,2n\}$ and takes it to $S\cup \{1\}$ if $1\not\in S$ and $S\setminus \{1\}$ if $1\in S$. This places sets of odd and even parity into bijection, showing the desired equality.

Answer (score 4):

Note that just using their series

$$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos x-i\sin x)\stackrel{\text{by series}}=e^{ix}e^{-ix}=1$$

Comment: The OP is asking how to prove it by squaring the two series and adding, I think.

Comment: @saulspatz It is obtained by series!

Comment: Gimusi not necessarily, there are other ways for last equality

Comment: @saulspatz If you read carefully the OP is asking "Can we prove $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1$ using just their series?" and not "Can we prove $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1$ using just their series in a complicated way?"

Comment: @KingTut others way? Euler is turning around in his grave!

Comment: This isn't worth arguing about, but I don't agree.  When he says, "In particular, I mean ...," then that's what he means.  The title is just a title.  The question is in the body.

Comment: It wasn't what I was asking about but I agree, this is a really cool answer. Thanks @gimusi!

Comment: @user539262 Thanks, I'm happy you have found that somehow useful as a short alternative!

Comment: I think some people misunderstand this answer. You can manually check with series that $e^{ix}e^{iy}=e^{i(x+y)}$, so it is in the spirit of the OP. Perhaps "by series" should appear on the final $=$ too.

Comment: I am not saying that the answer is bad, it's definitely nice. But it doesn't explicitly require series. Although Euler himself had used series to prove it. In various occasions op has written that he/she wants to manipulate series term by term ...

Comment: This is indeed the simpler approach +1. It replaces the series for circular functions with the series for exponential function which is far easier to manage (in terms of multiplication, differentiation and integration). Using this approach one can prove all the typical addition formulas of trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

Trying it out on my own using some points made in Milo's post (not going to accept my own answer, this is just for my own benefit):

$$\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2$$

$$=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^2$$

$$=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{x^{2n-2k+1}}{(2n-2k+1)!}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right) + \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\frac{x^{2n-2k}}{(2n-2k)!}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)$$

$$=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-2k-1)!(2k+1)!}\right) + \left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-2k)!(2k)!}\right)$$

$$=1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}(-1)^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2n-2k-1)!(2k+1)!} - \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(2n-2k)!(2k)!}\right)$$

$$=1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2n)!}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}\right)$$

$$=1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2n)!}\left(2^{2n-1} - 2^{2n-1}\right)$$

$$=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The essential result here is that $e^z e^{-z} = 1$ (cf. gimusi's answer).

In general, for $x$ with the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_k a_k z^k$ and $\sum_k b_k z^k$, a small amount of work shows that
$(\sum_k a_k z^k) (\sum_k b_k z^k) = \sum_k c_k z^k$, where $c_k = \sum_l a_l b_{k-l}$ (the series convolution).

In the above case, take $a_k = {1 \over k!}, b_k = (-1)^k {1 \over k!}$ for $k \ge 0$, and zero otherwise. Then
$c_k = 0$ for $k <0$, $c_0 = 1$  and for $k >0$, we have
$c_k = \sum_{l=0}^k {1 \over k!} (-1)^{k-l} {1 \over (l-k)!} = \sum_{l=0}^k (-1)^{k-l} \binom{k}{l} {1 \over k!} = (1-1)^k {1 \over k!} = 0$.

Hence $e^z e^{-z} = 1$.

Then $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x =(\cos x + i \sin x) (\cos x - i \sin x) = e^{ix} e^{-ix} = 1$.